# Kotlin shortcut for assigning method parameter to a field in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

In Android Studio, while I am working on a Java class when i press  <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd>  and assign method parameters to class member fields.

But when I use Kotlin there are no suggestions to this functionality.

Could I create a new suggestion for this or is there any way to assign parameters to the fields?

Java class suggestion:

[image: java class suggestion]

Kotlin class suggestion:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In kotlin you don't have to write a setter method in order to do this, that's probably why you don't get the suggestion.

In your example, if you wanted to have an `authPresenter` field with getters and setters, you'd declare it as a `var` and kotlin provides the rest:

```
class AuthenticationView(...) {
    var authPresenter: AuthPresenter? = null
}
```

This gives us a nullable `AuthPresenter`. And the idiomatic way to call this:

```
val view = AuthenticationView(...)
view.authPresenter = AuthPresenter(...)
```

Under the covers, that call to `.authPresenter = someObject` is turned into `setAuthPresenter(someObject)`.

If you were to call this from Java, you'd see the `getAuthPresenter()` and `setAuthPresenter()` automatically generated for you.

In short: the reason the reason the option isn't there for Kotlin, is because there is a more idiomatic way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Todd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48138239/1856562) answer, It's not required to write setter/getter methods like java.

If we want to declare our setter/getter, We have to declare a `var` and write get() and set(value) like this:

```
class AuthenticationView(...) {
    var authPresenter: AuthPresenter? = null
        get() = field
        set(value) {  
           field = value
           ....
        }
```

> I think it's a property field that I have seen something like this in
>   C#

Then if you wanna to set or get authPresenet just do this:

```
//set
authenticationView.authPresenter = object

//get
object = authenticationView.authPresenter
```

We can see codes like this in kotlin like setting `TextView`'s text or `View`'s background